# How assignment works in JS for objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wonder what happens when I try to assign one object to another?

```
function make(g: any, b: any) {
    g = b;
}


let obj = {id: 1};
let obj2 = {id: 2};

make(obj, obj2);

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj2);
```

From point of view memory, what happens? As we know value is passed by link for object, it means `g` will not be changed.

Why this code works different?

```
function make(g: any) {
    g = {};
}

let obj = {id: 1};
make(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: *"I wonder what happens"* Just try it?

Comment: I mean what happens in memory, not visual

Comment: It's the same as `a = {foo: 1}; b = a;` - you assign a new name to an old object.

Comment: `g` is a reference that points to some memory that stores `obj`. `b` is a reference that points to some memory that stores `obj2`. `make()` overwrites the content of `g` with the content of `b`. `g` and `b` only exist in `make()`. Right now your script is a big no-op.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language